# How to make little search in Django

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views

I want to make search function in my project, with Model Agreements

```
from django.db import models


class Agreements(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=128) # this i want to use to search
    email = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    creation_date = models.DateField()
    conclusion_date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.username)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.db.models import Q
from connections.models import Agreements, Connections


def index(request):
    context = {
        'index': Agreements.objects.all(),
        'HM': Connections.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request, 'list_agreements.html', context)


class Search(ListView):
    template_name = 'list_agreements.html'
    context_object_name = 'Agreements'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Agreements.objects.filter(username__icontains=self.request.GET.get('q'))

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['q'] = self.request.GET.get('q')
        return context
```

my urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from connections.views import index, Search

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', index, name='index'),
    path('search/', Search.as_view(), name='search'),
]
```

[enter image descri[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UfvF.png)ption here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gClVN.png)

my list_agreements.html (only important parts)

```
<form class="d-flex" role="search" action="{% url 'search' %} " method="get">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="q">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="limiter">
<div class="container-table100">
<div class="wrap-table100">
<div class="table100 ver1">
<div class="table100-firstcol">


</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="wrap-table100-nextcols js-pscroll">
<div class="table100-nextcols">
<table>
<thead>
<tr class="row100 head">
<th class="cell100 column2">ФИО</th>
<th class="cell100 column3">Почта</th>
<th class="cell100 column4">Номер телефона</th>
<th class="cell100 column5">Создания договора</th>
<th class="cell100 column6">Заключение договора</th>
</tr>
</thead>
{% for Agreements in index %}
<tbody>
<tr class="row100 body">
<td class="cell100 column2">{{ Agreements.username }}</td>
<td class="cell100 column3">{{ Agreements.email }}</td>
<td class="cell100 column4">{{ Agreements.phone_number }}</td>
<td class="cell100 column5">{{ Agreements.creation_date }}</td>
<td class="cell100 column6">{{ Agreements.conclusion_date }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

I execpted to see in ФИО username Иван Градинар Дмитривич, but i get empty list

Answer (score 1):

```
<form class="d-flex" role="search" action="{% url 'search' %} " method="get">
<input class="form-control me-2" type="search" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="q">
<button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
 </nav>
    <div class="limiter">
    <div class="container-table100">
      <div class="wrap-table100">
        <div class="table100 ver1">
         <div class="table100-firstcol">
    </tbody>
    </table>
       </div>
         <div class="wrap-table100-nextcols js-pscroll">
         <div class="table100-nextcols">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr class="row100 head">
         <th class="cell100 column2">ФИО</th>
         <th class="cell100 column3">Почта</th>
         <th class="cell100 column4">Номер телефона</th>
         <th class="cell100 column5">Создания договора</th>
         <th class="cell100 column6">Заключение договора</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>

    <tbody>
      {% for Agreements in index %}
         <tr class="row100 body">
             <td class="cell100 column2">{{ Agreements.username }}</td>
             <td class="cell100 column3">{{ Agreements.email }}</td>
             <td class="cell100 column4">{{ Agreements.phone_number }}</td>
             <td class="cell100 column5">{{ Agreements.creation_date }}</td>
             <td class="cell100 column6">{{ Agreements.conclusion_date }}</td>
         </tr>
     {% endfor %}

     {% for Agreements in object_list %}
       <tr class="row100 body">
         <td class="cell100 column2">{{ Agreements.username }}</td>
         <td class="cell100 column3">{{ Agreements.email }}</td>
         <td class="cell100 column4">{{ Agreements.phone_number }}</td>
         <td class="cell100 column5">{{ Agreements.creation_date }}</td>
         <td class="cell100 column6">{{ Agreements.conclusion_date }}</td>
       </tr>
     {% endfor %}
 </tbody>
```

Here **object_list** contains the list of objects returned by your search view just like your index. get method adds object list to the context.Append the code in list_agreements.html.

Comment: Oh my lord, Thank you very much!! i just copied your html and now it is working, it was really usefyl